# Copy AWS quicksight data sets and dashboards over multiple data sources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

We have multiple data sources with the exact same data model (one instance for each customer). We are using AWS Quicksight to create dashboards to view the data. We want to be able to clone or copy one dashboard created on one data source to a new data source using the SDK or AWS CLI. I can see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/index.html) that I can use `describe-dashboard` or `describe-data-set` to get the details. I also know creating data-sources and dashboards are possible but I don't see a way to configure it using details we got from the `describe` methods mentioned above. How can we create "copies" of quicksight dashboards? They are all in the same account and region.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way is to "Save As" in the Dashboard and save as a Analysis. Then change the Datasets in the "new" Analysis and save it again as a Dashboard. You can then repeat the process for each and every Dashboard you wish to create.

For a programmatic way try out the following:

```
aws quicksight create-dashboard --aws-account-id <Account ID> --dashboard-id <any ID> --name <any dashboard name> --source-entity file://createDashboard.json --region <region>
```

where the JSON is:

```
{
  "SourceTemplate": {
    "DataSetReferences": [
      {
    "DataSetPlaceholder": "placeholder", // Place holder you provided when creating the template.
    "DataSetArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-2:<Account ID>:dataset/<Dataset ID>" // ARN of the data set
      }
    ],
    "Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight: ap-southeast-2:<Account A ID>:template/<Template ID>"
  }
}
```

update the permission of the dashboard using, once it is created:

```
aws quicksight update-dashboard-permissions --aws-account-id <Account ID> --dashboard-id <new Dashboard ID> --grant-permissions file://permission.json
```

where permission.json is similar to below (to grant co-owner access to the dashboard):

```
[
  {
    "Principal": "arn:aws:quicksight:<region>:<Account ID>:user/default/<Quicksight user name>", // QuickSight user ARN who needs access to the dashboard
    "Actions": ["quicksight:DescribeDashboard","quicksight:ListDashboardVersions","quicksight:UpdateDashboardPermissions","quicksight:QueryDashboard","quicksight:UpdateDashboard","quicksight:DeleteDashboard","quicksight:DescribeDashboardPermissions","quicksight:UpdateDashboardPublishedVersion"]
  }
]
```

then create an Analysis from this dashboard, share it with other users via the QuickSight console.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, this doesn't seem like a very good idea. Problem: You have millions of users, you want to use the same dashboard parametized with the specific viewing user's data set. The solution is to duplicate the dashboard millions of times? A. I'm sure that is inefficient possibly costly B. What if you want to update the dashboard?

Comment: The question was about creating a dashboard from an existing one, and just changing the datasets used in it. (as datasets are related to data-sources, I am assuming that is what the user wants). A config/json file can be used to enter the details of the datsets and users and then run the API to invoke and create multiple copies of it. A. This will not be costly, inefficient for millions, maybe. B. The dashboard gets updated via the analysis or the datasets data. The user here just wants to duplicate the same and not make changes to it. For making changes, that would be a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is analysis in quicksight, based on which you create dashboards, so to achieve this, you can use templates, they have versioning and can easily solve your issue, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTemplate.html) you can have look into details
So the process can be, you have analysis based on a few datasets, you create template, and use them to create dashboards, when you apply template you indicate new datasets based on another datasources that's how you switching datasources